# VST Host for live keyboard performance

Tags: windows, music

I need a PC-compatible software like MainStage... the features I need:

- Be able to add external VST plugins like Omnisphere, Alicia's Keys
- Connect my midi keyboard and midi controller (nanokontrol2)
- Have a GUI where I can add virtual knobs, faders, and link then to the controller, so I can see when I move something and know what is changing is in that plugin
- Create setlist, so I can have one file with all the songs I'll play that day, and every song has its plugins and settings.

I've tried Cantabile, Forte, Ableton Live, but none of those seem to have all the features Mainstage has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, Akai Pro's VIP has all the features you mentioned. The very, very cool part about it is that you can run it either as a standalone app, or run it *inside* you DAW as a VST. You might want to try running it inside Ableton Live and see what setup you can come up with that suits all of your needs.

Unfortunately, it's not FOSS, but you mention that you're on PC, so that must not bother you much. ;) The setup I suggested is one that I've successfully tried in the past, but now I'm on Linux and using nearly exclusively FOSS, so I can't advise you regarding newer features of the software that I've not come across yet.

**Link:** https://www.akaipro.com/products/new-products/vip

By the way, VIP comes free with some AKAI products, including the cheaper miniature MIDI controllers. Might be worth looking into for you.

**P.S.** I'm aware I'm 6.75 years late. In this answer, "you" means either the asker who has not yet found a solution (I hope for him that that is not the case) or anybody who took the time to read my answer.